# git: Linux-Next, how to reset linux-next to a particular date?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I know if we know a commit id, then we can use reset --hard to that commit:

> git reset --hard [[commit_id]]

`Question 1：` if I want to find a commit of a specified date, how to do that?

Looks like Linux-next will have a tag for each date, for example, this:

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tag/?id=next-20151001

This is the tag of Oct 1, so that I can easily find that day's commit is 991f9697366015fef03eeeddb4d1ba0f44ff3dc7.

But, if I want to access Aug 1st's commit, via this link: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/tag/?id=next-20150801

It will tell me bad tag. Why?

`Question 2:` How could I find a commit 3 months ago?

For example, I know a commit on June 4, the commit id is: 94feb25d6fcd34b0d45c18cf0185d83d0c13c60a

But in my cloned Linux-next, if I run below command, it will complaint invalid commit; if I run

> git show 94feb25d6fcd34b0d45c18cf0185d83d0c13c60a

, it will complaint bad object.

How do I reset Linux-next to 3 months ago?

> user@test_machine MINGW64 /d/Test/linux-next ((e1883c6...)|BISECTING)
>   $ git show 94feb25d6fcd34b0d45c18cf0185d83d0c13c60a fatal: bad object
>   94feb25d6fcd34b0d45c18cf0185d83d0c13c60a

Comment: have you done a `git fetch` lately?

Comment: linux-next tree is not *everyday* tagged tree. Some of the days (usually weekends and holidays of maintainer) are absent there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the linux-next git tree is rebased everyday and previous tags and objects will disappear from the repository.

However, there is linux-next-history which should carry all the necessary objects:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next-history.git/

Comment: Thanks! Now I am able to find a commit of a particular date from the history tree. For example, for June 04, the commit is 94feb25d6fcd34b0d45c18cf0185d83d0c13c60a. But for the second question: why Linux-next compliant this is a invalid object? I think even the tags have been moved to history tree, but the commit should be in Linux-next. Am I right?

Comment: no, the tree gets garbage collected and the unreferenced objects disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `--since` and `--after` as specified in `man git-log`.